# Get value from string and put in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string, for example:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=2827619"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://track.adform.net/C/?bn=2827619;C=0" target="_blank">
<img src="http://track.adform.net/adfserve/?bn=2827619;srctype=4;ord=[timestamp]" border="0" width="728" height="90" alt=""/>
</a>
</noscript>

<script language="javascript" src="http://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=2826814"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://track.adform.net/C/?bn=2827619;C=0" target="_blank">
<img src="http://track.adform.net/adfserve/?bn=2827619;srctype=4;ord=[timestamp]" border="0" width="728" height="90" alt=""/>
</a>
</noscript>
```

Now i want to get **bn=numbers** in an array.
But only one from each script. Not duplicate.
And i wait the size of each banner in same array.
Anyone know how to do?

Comment: what is the workflow, and my apologies for SO contributors, but what have you tried?!

Comment: Which bn do you want to find? Because the ones in the `<a>` and `<img>` tags are all duplicates in this case, so you want to get them from the `src`s of the `script` tags?

Comment: rolfv1: I want the bn from the src in javascript code. bn=2826814 and bn=2826819

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

- Use a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to get the elements inside the `<script>` tag
- Use [`$dom->getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) and retrieve all the `<a>` tags
- Use [`$elem->getAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) to get the `href` value
- Use string functions like [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) or a regular expression to extract the values you need
- Use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) or [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) to split the numbers and store them in an array